# Why does my Android 2.3 widget not respond to a click after booting?

Tags: android, android-widget, click, boot

I have an app with a widget. I want to start the app with the widget but after booting my widget does not respond to a click. Only after starting the app normally (and closing it again) does the widget start to respond to the click on the widget itself.

This is how I setup the widget with the AppWidgetProvider:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{   final int ids = appWidgetIds.length;

    for(int i=0;i<ids;i++)
    {   int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestReceiver.class);            
        intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
        intent.setClassName(TestReceiver.class.getPackage().getName(), TestReceiver.class.getName());

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pi);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetclock, "Loading...");

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

What do I have to change so that my app registers clicks on the widget after a boot without having to start it first at least once ?

Comment: Why are you using an action *and* a class? Typically you use one or the other.

Comment: Because otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: "Because otherwise it doesn't work" -- it works for everybody else. Perhaps you should spend some time learning how `BroadcastReceivers` and the `Intent` system works, then (and only then) try to write an app widget.

Comment: I did try that at first and strangely enough it does not work for me which I did find very surprising. And as for your ludicrous notion to only write an app *after* I know all about anything I need, then I absolutely disagree because the best way to learn something like this is by "learning by doing". And I'd also advise YOU to learn some manners and then (and only then) post on the internet because you sound like a condescending elitist.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a BroadcastReceiver that responds to the BOOT broadcast and resets the widget's PendingIntent: I don't believe widget PendingIntents survive device reboots.